# Create entity bean from existing Database through glassfish resource (connection pool)

Tags: netbeans, glassfish, persistence, hsqldb, entity-bean

I want to create an entity class from database. My database would be HSQL and i use file to store the data.

I have no problem to config the connection pool to connect to this database @ glassfish The name of the resource which uses the connection pool (**HSQL-file**) is **HSQLJdbcResource**:

[image]

And no problem to reach this resource from a JSP file, this code works perfectly:

[image]

But i do have a problem, when i want to create the entity class from database with the netbeans wizard, because somehow the neatbeans can't find the driver for this :

[image]

I have the driver and attached to the project and also i can manage to create the entity class trough std datasource but i want trought glassfish resource, because if dont do the way like this --- the file will be locked because of my JPA which use glassfish resource and connection pool... Vicious Circle, is there any solution for this?

[image]

Comment: Your pictures are too big. Of original (1344px) is reduced to 640px and therefore no longer legible. I cut the pictures and unnecessary areas left out.

Answer (score 2):

1. Please check to see if the driver path is correct.
2. Add the hsql driver in your system **class path**.

Also, this might be helpful: http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch04.html

Comment: Hi, driver path is i think correct because netbeans doesn't show "resolve reference problem". And what do you mean adding system class path? I dont think it will solve the problem but i will give it a try;) After i've done, i will let you know about the result! Appreciate your answer.
Regards,
Czupe

Comment: The bounty just go away, how can i give you? I still do not find a solution :( but at least you work with this and give some hint.

Comment: Thanks. I am happy that it helped in any way. You can of course add your own solution if you found it and accept it :)